# File upload to web server using C#

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to upload file in web server as following using C#

```
try
{
    // create WebClient object
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    string myFile = @"D:\test_file.txt";
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    // client.UploadFile(@"http://mywebserver/myFile", "PUT", myFile);
    client.UploadFile(@"http://localhost/uploads", "PUT", myFile);
    client.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

But every time I am getting this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: What is your server code? Is it an MVC action?

Comment: Are you sure you need a PUT could it be a POST you need to send?

Comment: Is there need server side code?. I thaught file will be uploaded to desired folder in server. If needed what will be server side code please.

Comment: The error message says that PUT method is not allowed by the given server. It requires you code for the server, you can create an MVC application with a controller, a put method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have solved this using the POST method and server side code:

**C# code**

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string myFile = @"D:\test_file.txt";
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    client.UploadFile(@"http://localhost/uploads/upload.php", "POST", myFile);
    client.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

**Server side PHP code** upload.php

```
<?php
    $filepath = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($filepath,"test_file.txt");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the "PUT" method you are using is not allowed by the server. Check the response headers for allowed methods.  More info [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6).

Or check the documentation for the application to which you are trying to upload the file.

Answer (score 1):

the error is showing that you need to register with the service which you are using

in the case of wcf you can register like this

> "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication
>   Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r

[HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)